# ElasticSearch doesn't start after upgrade from 2.3.1 to 5.6.4

Tags: elasticsearch, start

I was running on elasticsearch 2.3.1, but I had to upgrade to 5.6.4 (because I wanted to install Kibana/Sense), but ElasticSearch won't start anymore.

This is **log** from ElasticSearch:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The index [[cyclone3.mysite_sk/Qf5ccdWNRYKFGs4lBffSAQ]] was created with version [1.2.1] but the minimum compatible version is [2.0.0-beta1]. It should be re-indexed in Elasticsearch 2.x before upgrading to 5.6.4.
```

And lot of the same errors.

Yes I understand that I need to reindex, but how? And does I lose all data?

**THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE OF [ElasticSearch doesn't start after installing 5.6.4](https://serverfault.com/questions/883269/elasticsearch-doesnt-start-after-installing-5-6-4) BECAUSE THIS IS ON THE DIFFERENT SERVER**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to re-index to be able to do that. Follow the following guide for help on how to do it

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/reindex-upgrade.html

Comment: But it is Reindex before upgrading, I already upgraded it (I think, because I cannot run "curl -XGET 'localhost:9200'", because I cannot start ElasticSearch). I upgraded it by executing 5.6.4 deb file.

Comment: @tomsk You can still probably reindex, but you need to delete the bad indexes first. The data you have won't work with 5.x.

Comment: Don't worry, elasticsearch sucks for everyone, just ask Nick Craver

Comment: But if I delete indexes I will lost data, no? And how can I reindex if elasticsearch wont start.